# how to get the height of avl tree in java

Tags: java, avl-tree

i tried this function

```
private int height(AVLNode t )
{
    return t == null ? -1 : t.height;
}
```

i don't know what that method do can anyone explain it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method returns height of the `AVLNode`, -1 otherwise. The line `return t == null ? -1 : t.height` is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Is equivalent to

```
if (t == null) {
    return -1
} else {
    return t.height
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The default approach is to use recursion to determine the height.

```
private int height(AVLNode t) {
    return t == null ? -1 : 1 + Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right));
}
```

Comment: Although for larger problems, you can imagine how this becomes slower. That's why during initialization of this node, it might be better to save the height as an instance variable using its parent's height. But for the problem OP is talking about, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: I was puzzled concerning the use of the function, since its private and takes a Node as parameter. If the nodes know their height, why add the non-null check except for empty trees, but then again why is there a parameter, if its supposedly only used with t == root. So I figured I'd suggest the recursive way.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the height of the AVLNode. If the AVLNode is null it returns -1. If the AVLNode is not null it returns the height of the AVLNode.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int height(AVLNode t) {

        if (t == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + Math.max((t.getLeft() != null ? t.getLeft().getHeight() : -1),
                (t.getRight() != null ? t.getRight().getHeight() : -1));

}
```